# Wordpress permalink 404- Wordpress installed in Tomee using JavaBridge

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, permalinks, apache-tomee

I have a website https://example.com which is running using Apache Tomee. I decided to integrate Wordpress for blogs. So I created a directory called blog under my webapps. As wordpress is PHP and tomee is J2EE I used JavaBridge to make it work. The https://example.com/blog is successfully installed. The problem now is I need to make permalinks work. I get 404 Error. 
I have enabled AllowOverride in httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I created .htaccess in blog folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My httpd.conf file is given below,

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   SSLEngine on
   SSLProxyEngine ON
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/xxx.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/yyy.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^/$ /searc [R=301]
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    ErrorLog logs/yourdomain.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/yourdomain.com-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What else I should do to make permalinks work

Comment: Please try to update and save permalink option in backend side. after again refresh the page.

Comment: I am new to Php and wordpress. Kindly help me out with the steps.

Comment: I am sharing with you one blog link as per your comment - https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-the-404-error-for-wordpress-websites. But there are three options for solve your solution, 1. you can use the plugin like Redirection -  https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/   2. Fix Your Permalink Settings Manually .  3. Edit Your .htaccess File Manually - that's you have already try.